# Is there an equivalent to the RxJS v4 case operator in RxJS v5?

Tags: rxjs5

I found the docs for the old `case` operator here: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/case.md

It is not listed in the migration guide:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/stable/MIGRATION.md

Is there some combination of supported operators that would provide the same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxJS v4 `Rx.Observable.case(selector, sources, [elseSource|scheduler])`, example given is

```js
var sources = {
    'foo': Rx.Observable.return(42),
    'bar': Rx.Observable.return(56)
};

var defaultSource = Rx.Observable.empty();

var source = Rx.Observable.case(
    function () {
        return 'foo';
    },
    sources,
    defaultSource);
```

I guess you could could do this in RxJS v5

```js
var sources = {
    'foo': Rx.Observable.return(42),
    'bar': Rx.Observable.return(56)
};

var defaultSource = Rx.Observable.empty();

var source = Rx.Observable.of('foo')
  .mergeMap(srcName => {
    const src = sources[srcName];
    return src || defaultSource;
  })
```

Would be interested to know where you are using / want to use this operator.

Comment: Thanks! I am introducing `redux-observable` into a React app. I have a sort of dynamic routing situation which is currently being handled by a `thunk` with a `switch` statement. So based on the value of the action payload I want to dispatch one of several actions.

Comment: Can I use it for angular 6 validations e.g. for select element value value changes observable to trigger validations based on value selected